# How to check if a process has been finished?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process

This is how I used to check if a child process has been finished in C/cC++ language:

```
waitpid(job.pid,&tmp,WNOHANG)>=0;
```

But after some reading I think it's wrong since I am asking if waitpid finished successfully or not and not asking if the process was finished or not.

How can I fix this?

Comment: As written, it is an expression that doesn't directly assign to anything (`tmp` is assigned to as a side-effect of the call to `waitpid()`, if it detects an exited process).  As part of an `if` condition, it could be useful.  Maybe you should use `pid_t corpse = waitpid(…);`? 
 The `WNOHANG` means you'll often get an error (`-1`) returned and `errno` will be set to `EAGAIN` (meaning you might be successful in a future call, roughly — you'd get `ECHILD` if the child had died and had already been waited for).

Comment: The oddities of this function is a good reason to wrap it in a function that you reuse for your projects. Having a good read of the man page and writing this right once will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @EmanuelP that's what I am asking help with, why should I save the result in a variable? the result means if waitpid worked or not, not if the process finished or still running

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you show me please how it will look like, I am still confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When called like that, `waitpid` can return three things

- 0: Status is not available. That means the process is still running.
- -1: An error. `errno` should be checked. It can be `EINTR`, in which case you should just try calling `waitpid` again. It can also be `ECHILD`, in which case you either already established the process had ended earlier, or it is an invalid/unrelated pid. If this happens, something is wrong in your program's logic.
- The pid you asked for. In this case the process ended. Exactly *how* it ended, you can check using the value returned in the second argument, `tmp` in your case. There are various macros explained in the man page about this value.

Thus, without caring for the process exit status, you can check it like this:

```
bool isdone(pid_t pid)
{
    int status;
    while((pid_t r = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) != pid)
    {
        if(r == 0) return false;
        if(errno == EINTR) continue;
        // handle errors
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In some cases, returning -1 with errno set to ECHILD is normal and does not mean there is a logic error.

Comment: @zwol Can you clarify? In what cases does that happen?

Comment: The example I have in mind is if you are looping over `waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)` after receiving a SIGCHLD.  Then receiving _either_ a 0 return value, _or_ a -1 return value with errno set to ECHILD, simply means that there are no more statuses to be reported and the loop should end.