# C waitpid, is this a contradiction?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process

In my previous question: [How to check if a process has been finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67155369/how-to-check-if-a-process-has-been-finished)

you showed me how to check if a child process is finished or not yet, the code was something like this:

```
pid_t r = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)//if r==pid then process finished
```

what if I want to wait for the process to finish (supposing it's still running)?

I read in the internet that the solution is the same, ie:

```
pid_t r = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)
```

does that mean we have same command for 2 different jobs? that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Note: In my previous question I only wanted to ask if process finished or not yet (not waiting for it to finish)

Comment: *> what if I want for the process to finish* - do you mean you want to *kill* it? Then you would use `kill` to send a signal to that process. Or use some dedicated mechanism if you programmed it. There is no contradiction, it is wrong description of the problem.

Comment: What do you think `WNOHANG` means?

Comment: @EugeneSh. please read the updates version I meant to wait

Comment: @EmanuelP it means "return immediately if no child has exited." what If I want to wait that's my question...

Comment: Then don't use `WNOHANG`..

Comment: You want it to wait. So you want it to not "return immediately if no child has exited." So you don't use WNOHANG.

Comment: then what to use in this question (the previous question is correct to use WNOHANG)

Comment: Use `0`. Also read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

Comment: Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and a good [operating system textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: @EugeneSh. why not WUNTRACED

Comment: Because it is used for specific usecases. Do you expect the process to be `ptrace`ed? Do you want your program to have specific behavior in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you read that `waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)` blocks, but this is wrong. To block until the process ends*, use

```c
waitpid(pid, &status, 0)
```

From the man page for `waitpid`:

> All of these system calls are used to wait for state changes in a child of the calling process

`WNOHANG` overrides this.

> `WNOHANG` return immediately if no child has exited.

---

* If you have signal handlers, it can also return (with error `EINTR`) when interrupted by a signal.

Comment: You don't really need to have signal handlers installed for a signal to interrupt a syscall.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli, I'm unaware of a situation where that's true. Please enlighten. To my knowledge, syscalls are interrupted to give handlers a chance to run. (And even then, I think you can set the syscalls to automatically restart.) With no handlers, there's no reason to interrupt, so they don't.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of a case like e.g. SIGINT/SIGUSR, but those would terminate the entire process, not just interrupt the syscall.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Accidental extras "not" in there, but yeah. They may kill the process, but at issue was when they "return (with error `EINTR`)".

Comment: To be fair, seems like I'm half-right, according to [`man 7 signal`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html): *"On Linux, even in the absence of signal handlers, certain blocking interfaces can fail with the error EINTR [...]"*. It is not the case for `waitpid` though, so all good here.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli When you said there was a way, I had to guesses: some `sigaction` flag, and SIGSTOP/SIGCONT. I give myself a gold star :) Thanks for the info